# Pandas.read_csv() Decoding Error tokenizing data because of a comma in data

Tags: python, pandas, csv, decoding

I am having trouble reading in a csv that contains a comma within a row value.

An example row including the data causing the issue (afaik) is as follows:

['true',47,'y','descriptive_evidence','n','true',66,[81,65]]

I *think* that the [81,65] entry is being scanned literally and thus treated as two entries [81 and 65]. Is there any way to override this in pandas, or do i have to manually replace the comma prior to reading into a dataframe?

From reading other answers, I am aware of the possibility of skipping rows using something like **error_bad_lines=False**, but in this case i cant afford to skip these entries.

Best Wishes :)

Comment: Do you have any control over the data itself? e.g., are you exporting it somewhere? You could then change the delimiter; otherwise, if you know how many columns should be contained in the dataset, you could write a custom cleaning script that replaces the commas with another delimiter, or you check whether the comma is contained inside squared brackets using regular expressions

Comment: @moritz Yes technically. The data is generated by an online experiment written in JS.  Going forward I can change the way I store the tuple data, but for the current dataset I have to analyse the data as is.

Comment: Then probably the other options I described would be the way to go!

Comment: I think Regex makes the most sense - I'm quite unfamiliar with it. Would you happen to know the relevant expression for  replacing a comma with a '.' . the data will always be [] with 2 2digit numbers either side of the comma for reference.

Comment: Replace `\[(\d\d),(\d\d)\]` with `[$1.$2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `sep` with regex but it will be using **python** `engine` and not **c** and it can be memory/time consuming. Here is the solution if you would like to go with this:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
'true',47,'y','descriptive_evidence','n','true',66,[81,65]
```

```py
pd.read_csv("./file_name.csv",sep=r",(?![^[]*\])",engine="python")
```

```
|     | 1      | 2   | 3   | 4                      | 5   | 6      | 7   | 8       |
| --- | ------ | --- | --- | ---------------------- | --- | ------ | --- | ------- |
| 0   | 'true' | 47  | 'y' | 'descriptive_evidence' | 'n' | 'true' | 66  | [81,65] |
```

Comment: Thanks this was a really helpful solution! I lack the reputation to give you an upvote but i would if i could :)

Comment: If this answered your question you can mark it as answer as well ;). But I suggest you not to use this on large number of dataset as it can be resource consuming. If possible change the way you are storing via JS

Answer (score 0):

This approach will standardize your file a bit, then load it in pandas.

a sample file:

```
['Bool','low_number','char','string','char2','bool','high_number','list_using_quotechar']
['true',47,'y','descriptive_evidence','n','true',66,[81,65]]
['true',47,'y','descriptive_evidence','n','true',66,[81,65]]
```

Code to standardize the file, and the load it:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('data_with_quote.csv') as original_file:
    with open('data_fixed.csv', 'w') as new_file:
        for line in original_file:
            line = line.replace('\n','') # remove newline so all lines are equal
            line = line[1:-1] # remove first and last charcter, '[' amd ']' respectively
            line = line.replace('[','"') # replace '[' with a quote_character that will work with pandas
            line = line.replace(']','"') # replace ']' with a quote_character that will work with pandas
            new_file.write(line + '\n')
            
your_data_as_df = pd.read_csv('data_fixed.csv',quotechar='"') # load file with quote_character from earlier
```